# Does redirecting assembly binding work for unit testing with a test runner?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, assembly-resolution

Ok, so here's the full description of the problem I'm having:

I am trying to use [NUnit ExtensionMethods](http://code.google.com/p/nunit-extmethods/) but whenever I run a test containing one of the extension methods using TestDriven.Net or if I just flat out try to load the assembly using a test-runner GUI (Icarus or NUnit) I get a FileNotFoundException.

Pounding head against a wall and digging in further I think I know what's wrong.  Cue reflector and yep, I can see that NUnit.Framework>ExtensionMethods.dll has a reference to

```
nunit.framework, Version=2.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77
```

and my current version of nunit that I'm including is

```
nunit.framework, Version=2.4.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77
```

Now I have never used assembly re-direction before but it seems like it would be a simple matter of adding an App.Config with the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity
                    name="nunit.framework.dll"
                    publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.4.6.0" newVersion="2.4.8.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and it is my understanding that calls to the 2.4.6 version (which does not exist on this machine) should automatically redirect to the 2.4.8 version.

This does not work however, and I suspect (but have not yet confirmed) that this is because test runners do not automatically read app.config files.

So my question's are as follows:

1. Am I right in my diagnosis of the
   problem?
2. Is assembly redirection the
       appropriate solution and am I doing
       it right?
3. How do I get this to work with the
   test runner?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work if you put the configuration settings in the correct .config file. Which one that is depends on the environment you are using to run the tests, but both NUnit and TestDriven.NET should support using *testassembly*.dll.config.
As for this is the appropriate solution, I would say yes. The only other possibility would be to use a publisher policy file, but you would need the private key used to compile NUnit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, never heard of testassembly.dll.config but thats what I was looking for.  In this case the NUnit Extensions is open source and  only about 70 lines of code so I just opened and recompiled with my version.  But this is good knowledge for next time.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer "testassembly.dll.config" is what the standard App.config file is transformed into a compile time. As far as I know the config is loaded by the .NET framework by default and NUnit/TestDriven.NET do not even know specifically about it

Comment: @Schneider: AFAIK this is only true for *.exe.config files, not for *.dll.config files, those have to be explicitly specified when the AppDomain is created.

Comment: I also found I had to explicitly tell it you use multiple AppDomains using the `/domain=multiple` switch.  See [this doc](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3) for more info

Comment: Coming back to this many years later - I nowadays almost always make my test assemblies console exes rather than dlls for precisely this reason. It makes it much much easier to use a config file - just use the standard app.config.

Comment: `/domain:multiple` fixed it for me. Also `/process:multiple` seems to work, but I think it does more than the required minimum

Comment: Adding both `--domain=multiple` and `--process=multiple` worked for me.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, making it an exe works, but so does setting App.config "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy if newer".